# Stop at first occurrence Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, file, directory, subdirectory

Is that possible to stop at first occurrence after found the file using cmdlet Get-ChildItem.

Ex: Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Include AnyFile.doc -File -Recurse | Get-Location

Comment: Yes, you pipe `Get-ChildItem` to `Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Hi Santiago, You are correct, it stopped at first occurrence, but returning the root path C:\. Which is not the correct subdirectory.

Comment: You still need to use `-Include AnyFile.doc -File -Recurse` tho. Preferable use `-Filter` instead of `-Include`

Comment: Now that is really working without -Filter @SantiagoSquarzon. Thank you very much

Comment: Is `Get-Location` pseudocode you're using to represent the problem? If you're looking to get the path of the file(s), you can also specify the property name of `FullName` for the full path of the file, on your `Select-Object`.